# Activating/Deactivating game objects in hierarchy based on their names

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 10 game objects in my Hierarchy, say with names like David, James, Lisa and the like. All of these 10 game objects are children of another game object. The parent game object has a script component, in which there is a list, in which the 10 children's names are stored. Of course, this list is constantly being updated during the game, so sometimes not all of the children's names are stored. For example, at one point in the game, this game might have 7 names in it.

At the initial state, all of the 10 game objects in the hierarchy are deactivated. In the Update() function, I want to go through the list, activate first game object for 5 seconds, then deactivate it, and go to the next game object and do the same. And over and over. Is that possible? I mean, how can I set a link between the list in C# and the game objects in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to ask by why use names and not just standard unity properties?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectCycler : MonoBehaviour {

  public float durationInSeconds = 5.0f;
  public GameObject[] objectsToCycle;

  int currentNdx = 0;

  void Start()
  {
    StartCoroutine(Cycle());
  }

  IEnumerator Cycle() 
  {
    for(;;) {
      objectsToCycle[currentNdx].SetActive(true);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(durationInSeconds);
      objectsToCycle[currentNdx].SetActive(false);
      currentNdx = (currentNdx + 1) % objectsToCycle.Length;
    }
  }

}
```

Drag that script into any object. In the inspector expand the `objectsToCycle` property and set `size` to how many objects you want it to cycle. Drag the objects into it.

[image]

Running

[image]

Notice the order matches the order in the array of objects in the **inspector** (ObjectCycler, above the gif), not the order in the hierarchy. You can set any order you want by changing the order in the inspector.

Advangates

1. It's faster
2. You can easily set the order.

   Bill, Jill, Bob or Jill, Bill, Bob etc.
3. The objects don't have to be children
4. Objects can repeat

   Bill, Bob, Bill, Bob, Jill, Bob etc...
5. You can rename objects and it won't break
6. You can move objects in the hierarchy and it won't break

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I did what you said, and have the same 'problem' you have: the game objects don't get activated/deactivated in order (look at the gif file you have provided). What am I doing wrong? @gman

Comment: The gif file I provided shows them appear in the exactly the order they are in the array in the **inspector** (ObjectCycler, above the gif), not in the order they are in the **hierarchy**. If you want them in a different order change the order they are in the array. (drag objects from the hierarchy to the inspector to the element slots of the array in the order you want).  As for the small flash, that's just me not cutting my capture to a gif perfectly. Uploaded a new gif cut better

Answer (score 1):

If you only store the name of the game objects, you need to use `Transform.Find` to get the child game objects.

```
var go = transform.Find("David").gameObject;
```

Comment: Note: Find is expensive for performance. You should not use it if possible. It is possible to get a reference by parent/GetChild method or direct reference. Also it is much better to get gameobject reference by tag instead of name.

Comment: Thanks, @Mah. Then I'll have to use GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(). Right?

Comment: You may confuse with `GameObject.Find` and `Transform.Find`, the first one is expensive and marked by the offcial document, but the second one is a simple loop and compare method, it's not much expensive, if you look around the example scripts from Unity UI, they use `Transform.Find` to get the UI elements rather than create reference fields.

Comment: @shingo Well, both are "simple loop and compare" (at least I think they are since I don't really know the backend implementation), the difference is that Transform.Find only loop the children of a GameObject, while GameObject.Find loop the scene, that's why GameObject.Find is always expensive, while Transform.Find is not always expansive (but you need to be sure that the transform is a child of your GO). Still, the main problem about Find by Name I think is not the performance part but the unique reference... that's why i think is still better to use FindGameObjectsWithTag or get a direct ref

Comment: @Gordafarid I actually suggest you to use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html to navigate your scene and get a reference to the object you want to use, look at this link https://answers.unity.com/questions/205391/how-to-get-list-of-child-game-objects.html answer of pprofitt you can use a switch case for the tag name instead of if

Comment: Also: remember that you can use transform.childCount to get the number of children of a GameObject.